# como muestro un dato dentro de una lista doble

Tags: c#, .net

Quiero mostrar el dato del objeto mueble en la lista doble pero no se muestra adjunto código del método usado:

```
public void mostraradelanteatras() 
{
    nodos actual=new nodos();
    actual = primero;

    while (actual != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(actual.Dato);
        actual = actual.Siguiente;
    }
}
```

El actual.dato tiene dentro el objeto mueble.

Comment: Y de que tipo de datos es dato?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código completo? Porque al menos en el código que has escrito, no hay ninguna lista doble que se pueda imprimir.

Comment: dato es tipo mueble @Japv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr eso debes hacer un **casteo**:

```
Mueble m = ((Mueble)actual.dato);
Consola.WriteLine(m.NombreMueble);
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una **operación de casteo de tipos**, es decir el objeto que está en **dato** se convierte en un **objeto de tipo Mueble**, al usar las operaciones de casteo hay que ser muy cuidadosos ya que si casteamos a un tipo de datos que no es el correcto, ocurrirá un error.

**Nota**: asumo que dentro de tu tipo **Mueble** tienes una propiedad que es la que deseas imprimir, aquí yo asumo que se llama **NombreMueble**, tu tal vez tengas otro nombre, también puedes sobrescribir el **método ToString** como ya se te explicó en respuestas anteriores.